# Objectify Ofy() is not finding the "query" method

Tags: objectify

I am new to objectify, and reading a tutorial on how to query. For some reason when I type the following code:

```
Query q = ofy().query(UserChoice.class).filter("email", email);
```

My Eclipse gives me a error saying "The method query(Class) is undefined for the type Objectify"

I'm not sure what this means? I imported Objectify correctly by using the following:

```
import com.googlecode.objectify.Objectify;
import com.googlecode.objectify.ObjectifyService;

ObjectifyService.register(UserChoice.class);
```

Comment: how are you getting/calling the ofy object.  Can you attach that code?

Answer (score 1):

Objective doesn't have an actual query method.  In their [API](http://objectify-appengine.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/javadoc/com/googlecode/objectify/Objectify.html) you can see all the calls you can make on the `Objectify` object, `query()` isn't one of those.

It looks like there may be an older version of `Objectify` that has a `query` method.  The newest one ([Build version: 4.0a3](http://objectify-appengine.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/javadoc/com/googlecode/objectify/Objectify.html)) doesn't have it, but an older version ([Build version: 2.2.1](http://objectify-appengine.googlecode.com/svn-history/r543/trunk/javadoc/com/googlecode/objectify/Objectify.html)) does.  It looks like the class paths are the same, `com.googlecode.objectify.Objectify`.  Make sure to load in the correct one or you are using the proper version with the `query() call.

The [ObjectifyService](http://objectify-appengine.googlecode.com/svn-history/r543/trunk/javadoc/com/googlecode/objectify/ObjectifyService.html) you are using looks to be in the older version (2.2.1).